# Kotlin Getter/Setter causing infinite recursion

Tags: kotlin

I am like **one day new** to Kotlin, and facing a bit of issue understanding the very basic getter and setter.

Usecase:

simple Animal class with weight and height integer fields

There is another variable called volume which has backing get and set methods

I am trying to calculate the volume variable as weight*height

And also allowing someone to reset the volume variable frmo outside

However what ends up happening is kotlin obviously recalculates the volume variable. Not sure if this is because of field variable
However if i dont use a field keyword, setter method goes into recursion infinitely

```
class Animal(var weight :Int = 25, var height:Int = 56){
    init {
        println("initializing animal")
    }
    init {
        println("initializing animal2")
    }
    fun printAnimal(){
        println("size is $weight and height is $height")
    }
    var volume:Int = 0
        get():Int{
            println("inside get method")
            return weight*height
        }
        set(value:Int){
            println("inside set method")    
            field = value
        }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>){

    var animal = Animal()
    animal.printAnimal()
    animal.weight=54
    println("animal volume is ${animal.volume}")
    println("animal wieght is ${animal.weight}")
    animal.volume=200
    println("animal volume is ${animal.volume}")
}
```

The output is

```
initializing animal
initializing animal2
size is 25 and height is 56
inside get method
animal volume is 3024
animal wieght is 54
inside set method
inside get method
animal volume is 3024
```

Question: i am sure i am missing something very basic here. How can I set a value of a variable from outside so that it sticks and is not recalculated via get method

Comment: Suppose you _could_ set the volume — what effect should that have on the height and weight? (Scale one and leave the other alone, or vice versa, or both? What if that resulted in a non-integer value?) If the volume is in a fixed relationship with the height and weight, then you can't set one without affecting at least one of the others.

Comment: thank you @gidds to be honest i understand its not a real life use cases, and something i came up during tutorials/learning phase. but there must be normal get/set in instance variables in kotlin? or same way we have in java? how does that work in kotlin? is that specific for data classses only?

Comment: Have you seen [the Kotlin docs on properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html)?

Comment: i did actually.. that is where i found out about the identifier "field".  any ways thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn’t make logical sense for `volume` to be a `var` and have a setter because its value is dependent on other properties. If there was a way to change its value directly, it would become contradictory to the current value of `weight` and `height`. The `volume` property should only be a `val`.

Your code above sets the value of the backing field, which is pointless because the backing field is not used by the getter.

If you literally want to define this property to simply start ignoring the other two properties once the setter has been called the first time, then you must create a private Boolean property to keep track of whether the setter has ever been called before. Check this property and return `field` if the setter has ever been called. Change the Boolean property in the setter. Example:

```
private var isVolumeExplicitlySet = false

var volume:Int = 0
    get():Int{
        return if (isVolumeExplicitlySet) field else weight*height
    }
    set(value:Int){
        isVolumeExplicitlySet = true
        field = value
    }
```

---

In the comments, you said this was the code giving you an infinite loop:

```
var volume: Int = 0
    get():Int{
        return weight*height
    }
    set(value:Int){
        volume = value
    }
```

This is because by using the `volume` property by name in your setter, it is calling itself. It would be equivalent to this code in Java:

```java
private volume = 0;

public int getVolume() {
    return weight * height;
}

public void setVolume(int value) {
    setVolume(value);
}
```

Remember that in Kotlin, the backing field has no name. You need to refer to it by using `field`. When you set the `field`, it would be like this Java code:

```java
private volume = 0;

public int getVolume() {
    return weight * height;
}

public void setVolume(int value) {
    volume = value; // volume here is the backing field above, not the same method
}
```

Also, in this Java code you can see why merely setting the backing field is not sufficient to return the new value in your setter. You need some logic to determine whether you want to start using the backing field instead of basing it on other fields:

```java
private int volume = 0;
private boolean isVolumeExplicitlySet = false;

public int getVolume() {
    return isVolumeExplicitlySet ? volume : weight * height;
}

public void setVolume(int value) {
    volume = value; 
    isVolumeExplicitlySet = true;
}
```

Comment: If you want commentary on why you had an infinite loop, you’ll have to provide the code that produced it. Hard to guess what it looked like.

Comment: the code that produces infinite recursion if i do this var volume:Int = 0
        get():Int{
            println("inside get method")
            return weight*height
        }
        set(value:Int){
            println("inside set method")
            volume= value
        }  *** i think its because the setting of volume to a value keeps triggereing the set method again and again

Comment: i wonder if that is the case, how does get/set work in data classes in kotlin? is it only specific to data classes and cannot be applied on "normal" class?

Comment: Yes, if you call the property’s setter inside the property’s setter, you are creating an infinite loop. Using `field` is setting the backing field and is duplicating what you would do in Java. The difference is that the backing field has no name and you can only refer to it by using `field`.

Comment: When you don’t define a getter or setter, which is the way all the constructor properties of a data class are, then the property uses the default implementation whose getter simply returns the field’s value and whose setter simply changes the field’s value. This is not specific to data classes. You can define a property and not give it a custom getter or setter in any class.

Comment: @user1906450 I updated the answer to flesh out the explanation.